# An integral inequality

Tags: inequalities, integration

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be bounded with derivative $g'$.  I have shown that the following inequality holds for all $w\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}\bigg|w\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tg'(tw+x\sqrt{1-t^2})e^{-x^2/2}dxdt\bigg|\leq 8\sqrt{\pi}\|g\|_{\infty},
\end{equation}
where $\|g\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|g(x)|$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ I would like to prove that the following statement, which extends the above result:

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be bounded with derivative $g'$ and let $n$ be a postive integer.  Then, for all $w\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}\bigg|w\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^ng'(tw+x\sqrt{1-t^2})e^{-x^2/2}dxdt\bigg|\leq 8\sqrt{\pi}\|g\|_{\infty}.
\end{equation}
I used an indirect approach to prove the first inequality, which is not applicable to the second inequality.  However, I think that it should be possible to deduce the second inequality from the first inequality.

$\mathbf{PS:}$ Note that for the case that $g'$ has no sign changes (suppose, without lose of generality, that $g'$ is non-negative on $\mathbb{R}$), we can used the first inequality to prove the second:
\begin{align*}&\bigg|w\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^ng'(tw+x\sqrt{1-t^2})e^{-x^2/2}dxdt\bigg| \\
&\leq |w|\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^n|g'(tw+x\sqrt{1-t^2})|e^{-x^2/2}dxdt \\
&\leq |w|\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tg'(tw+x\sqrt{1-t^2})e^{-x^2/2}dxdt \\
&\leq 8\sqrt{\pi}\|g\|_{\infty},
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: I think you can easily reduce to the case of a monotone $g$ if you replace it with a primitive function of either $g'_+$ or $g'_-$. The double integral increases and $\|g\|_\infty$ does not change.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!  That answers my question.